# ImportError: No module named 'pymysql' in python 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the Visual Studio 2013 PTVS environment the command

import pymysql

work fine.

In the interpreter it gives the error:
ImportError: No module named 'pymysql' in python 3.4.3
The solutions in the other questions on this site refering to this problem do not solve it.
sys.path is:

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', 'C:\\SVN\\MyPrograms\\ELS Positions Database\\CSVImport\\CSVImport1\\"C:\\SVN\\MyPrograms\\ELS Positions Database\\CSVImport\\CSVImport1\\env\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql-0.6.6-py3.4.egg', '
:\\SVN\\MyPrograms\\ELS Positions Database\\CSVImport\\CSVImport1\\env\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql-0.6.6-py3.4.egg\\pymysql', 'C:\\SVN\\MyPrograms\\ELS Positions Database\\CSVImport\\CSVImport1\
env\\Lib\\site-packages"', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip', 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
>>>
```

PYTHONPATH is:

```
PYTHONPATH="C:\SVN\MyPrograms\ELS Positions Database\CSVImport\CSVImport1\env\Lib\site-packages\pymysql-0.6.6-py3.4.egg;C:\SVN\MyPrograms\ELS Positions Database\CSVImport\CSVImport1\env\Lib\site-
ackages\pymysql-0.6.6-py3.4.egg\pymysql;C:\SVN\MyPrograms\ELS Positions Database\CSVImport\CSVImport1\env\Lib\site-packages"
```

I suspect I am making some syntax error but cannot find where. Help appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is it using different interpreter? Check out `import sys ; print(sys.version)`

Comment: Mikko: C:\SVN\MyPrograms\ELS Positions Database\CSVImport\CSVImport1>^Z
C:\SVN\MyPrograms\ELS Positions Database\CSVImport\CSVImport1>python
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys;
>>> print (sys.version)
3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think that VS uses the 2.7 version of python and you are trying to use that library from the 3.4 version, try installing 2.7.

Or let me know what happen when you type `import pymysql` in the interpreter.

Comment: It works fine in VS environment. VS allows you you to specify the python environment and i have it set up for v3.4.

Comment: Correct insofar the v2.7 library was being used. A PYTHONPATH correction in the environment fixed it.